# find if 2 planes are parallel or not

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

I have 2 parallel planes with equation :

a.x + b.y + c.z +d = 0
a'.x + b'.y + c'.z +d = 0

And I need to demonstrate they are parallel.

I could read that they are parallel if they have "2 collinear normal vectors"
But I couldn't understand what it means?
Well, collinear mean parallel, but does it mean I need minimu 2 true sentences on these ones ?

a=k.a'
b=k.b'
c=k.c'

Excuse me if this is an easy issue, but just starting to learn back mathematics...

Comment: If the coefficients are nonzero, it simply means that $\dfrac a{a'}=\dfrac b{b'}=\dfrac c{c'}$.

Comment: The normal vectors are $(a, b, c)$ and $ (a', b', c')$. For them to be collinear, you need $ (a, b, c ) = k  ( a', b', c')$, which happens iff all 3 equations that you listed hold (not just min 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the equation of the plane in standard form $ax+by+cz = d,  (a,b,c)$ is the normal vector  to the plane.

If two planes are parallel then these normal vectors are scalar multiples of one another.

So, if $(a,b,c) = (ka',kb',kc')$ the normal vectors are parallel.  However, if also $d = kd'$ then they are the same plane.